# Why does read.csv fail inconsistently when part of a function/loop?

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a script that includes a function in which a csv file is downloaded by Selenium in Chrome browser.

The csv file download works consistently and the file is intact, however read.csv fails very inconsistently and returns an error as the csv gets read as a single column file at times (~50/50, but cannot determine why; the environment is empty at every start).

I tried sleep statements after the file download and a frustrated loop to call the script again in case no dataframe is produced;

How do I make the read.csv inside a function/loop work consistently?

edit:

This is the error message thrown in R (csv row/column structure not read correctly I'm assuming):

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
```

This is the full Selenium script that downloads the csv file (cleared out navigation / credentials) :

```
user_loader <- function(){
    #setup selenium
    rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever = "100.0.4896.60", port=netstat::free_port(), verbose=F)
    remDr <- rD[["client"]]
    remDr$open()
    #go to login page
    remDr$navigate("[...]")
    
    #fill login data and click login
    remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "manager_email")$sendKeysToElement(list("[...]"))
    remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "manager_password")$sendKeysToElement(list("[...]"))
    remDr$findElement(using = 'name', "commit")$clickElement()
    
    #go to users page 
    remDr$navigate("[...]")
    
    #wait until table is loaded
    rows <- remDr$findElements(using = "class name", "sorting_1")
    while (length(rows) < 2 ){
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      rows <- remDr$findElements(using = "class name", "sorting_1")
    }
    
    #download csv
    remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = ("//*[text()='CSV']"))$clickElement()
    
    #find downloaded file
    download_dir <- file.path("C:", "Users", Sys.info()[["user"]], "Downloads")
    file_name <- rownames(fileSnapshot(download_dir)$info[which.max(fileSnapshot(download_dir)$info$mtime),])
    
    #read csv
    df <- read.csv(file.path(download_dir, file_name))
    Sys.sleep(0.2)

    #goodbye server and file
    remDr$closeWindow()
    rD$server$stop()
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
    unlink(file.path(download_dir, file_name), recursive = FALSE, force = FALSE)
    
    #welcome data frame
    return(df)
  }

users <- user_loader()
```

Comment: Can you provide the selenium script so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: What is the error message when it fails?

Comment: I editet both into the original question. The file download works and the file structure doesn't change between successful and unsuccessful iterations.